# Can I use any micro usb cable to connect to ps 4 controller?

Tags: ps4

I want to ask about ps 4 controller, can I use any Micro USB cable to connect to ps4 controller and use it on pc ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should work out of the box for some more modern games such as Mortal Kombat X but for others like in my case Grid Autosport and Dirt you might need something to bridge the gap and have windows emulate it as a XBox device. I use [InputMapper](https://inputmapper.com/) (just keep it running while your controller is connected), works extremely well and you can use the touchpad to control your cursor as an added bonus.

Comment: ty for ur answer,but do I need gaming receiver like xbox 360 or ps 2 controller to connect it to pc ?

Comment: @MysteryQ A regular micro usb cable will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The PS4 controller uses a regular USB cable, and any USB cable can be used to connect the controller to either a PC or a PS4.

Also, if your PC supports Bluetooth, you can connect your PS4 controller that way as well.

Unfortunately, not many games support the PS4 controller, [so you'll need a wrapper for that](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144262/can-a-dualshock-4-replace-a-xbox-360-controller-on-the-pc).