# Does the steam copy of Rocket League have implicit support for PS4 Controllers?

Tags: steam, ps4, rocket-league

I bought Rocket League through Steam today and, on a whim, connected it to my PS4 controller.

Despite my expectations of having to download drivers or the like, it just... worked!

Is this something specific to Rocket League? Steam? Or are the PS4 controllers themselves able to install drivers? I know that in the past, I had to use dsFix to get Playstation Controllers working on PC.

I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: Related: [Can a Dualshock 4 replace a Xbox 360 controller on the PC?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/144262/46740) Rocket League probably supports both DirectInput (PS controller) and XInput (Xbox controller). Most games only support XInput, but since the PS4 controller explicitly supports DirectInput on PC (unlike the PS3 controller, which didn't support PC directly), it's possible that games are starting to support both. I think Witcher 3 also supports the PS4 controller, though I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: So, I've tried to play Witcher 3 with the PS4 controller, and it works. The game displays the Xbox icons, but the game is entirely playable without any wrapper. It might be a bit confusing if you see `X` and actually have to press `Square`, though.

Comment: @Nolonar That looks like a dupe of my question. Voting to close.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as a duplicate, it's about Rocket League specifically (the correct answer is:  Yes, Rocket League has complete support for DS4, no need for additional drivers or software, unlike many other games)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I, as the author, suggested it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Rocket League has complete support for the DS4, with the correct button-icons and everything.  There's no need to install additional drivers or software, unlike many other games.

Comment: Also supports DualShock 5 (DS5).